# What to Do when JDBC Driver is Invalid?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm working on a Java project that uses an Oracle database. When I create a new Oracle driver:

```
jdbcDriver driver = new jdbcDriver();
```

...I check it to see if it is valid using:

```
if (!driver.isValid())
{
   throw new UncheckedSqlException("jdbcDriver not valid");
}
```

What is the correct procedure if the driver is invalid? That is, there is no way to store the data and retry later asynchronously (i.e. without locking up the app), since the database is unavailable. Is the assumption that if I just retry a few times, I'll get a valid driver?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to EJP for correctly pointing out that jdbcDriver is a class in my code. That is correct -- it is a class in a code base I am working on. EJP requests to have the relevant details posted. Here they are.

```
package us.mydev.jdbc.util;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.sql.*;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import us.mydev.data.exception.UncheckedSqlException;

public class jdbcDriver
{
  [.....]
  public jdbcDriver()
  {
    try
    {
      m_iActiveConnections++;
      if (showLogMessages)
      {
        log.debug("jdbcDriver() created, hashcode = " + this.hashCode()
            + ",Active Connection Count is " + m_iActiveConnections);
        log.debug("Data Source is " + DS_STANDARDUSER);
      }

      InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
      DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup(DS_STANDARDUSER);

      mydevGetJDBCConn getConn = new sqlConn(ds);
      m_conn = getConn.getConnection();
      m_iDatabaseType = getConn.getDBType();

    }
    catch (NamingException _exp)
    { // handle any errors
      log.error("failed", _exp);
    }
  }


  public boolean isValid() throws SQLException
  {
    return m_conn != null && m_conn.isValid(10);
  }

  [.....]
}
```

I am finding that after this code:

```
jdbcDriver driver = new jdbcDriver();
boolean driverIsValid = driver.isValid();
```

...driverIsValid is `false` about once in every 1000 or so database accesses. I would imagine that this is an artifact of my current dev system -- I have Oracle running in a virtual machine.

Would it be unusual (or unheard of) for `driverIsValid` to be false in production in a situation like this? And if it is not unheard-of -- how is it usually handled, given that I can't save the relevant data to the database -- that is, can I just retry getting a database connection a few times and expect to get one?

**UPDATE #2**

Based on what I've learned from the responses, I need to ask this question using no code from the objects defined in the code base I am working on. I'm going to accept the answer provided by Wen-Bin Luo and re-ask the question more properly.

Comment: what is `jdbcDriver` ?

Comment: What is `jdbcDriver` ? Do you mean [java.sql.Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html) interface ?

Comment: if you want to access the db on the JDBC level (and not via some higher level abstraction like JPA, SpringData etc.) then maybe you should start with something like this: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/

Comment: The interface is imported from `import java.sql.*;`

Comment: What interface? All I can see here is the class name `jdbcDriver`, which is certainly *not* an interface and equally certainly *not* imported from `java.sql`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP I see what you are saying. class jdbcDriver calls `nc4GetJDBCConn getConn = new sqlConn( ds ); m_conn = getConn.getConnection();` to get a new connection and store it in a class variable. Is it common for the connection to be invalid immediately after the call to `getConn`?

Comment: I am not going to even comment on incomplete code or code in comments. If you want us to help you with your code you have to post it, all the relevant stuff, in your question, in a form that makes sense, without false assertions about what it is. The classes you mention are not interfaces or classes in `java.sql`, and there is no `isValid()` method in `java.sql` other than `java.sql.Connection.isValid(int timeout)`, which is not what you're calling. Do us and yourself a favour and explain yourself properly. Or see your question closed.

Comment: Thanks for this input EJP. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are meaning if a connection is still valid at time of checking. The `isValid` method returns whether or not a connection is usable. This method can be invoked at any time you like and allows you to set a timeout.
According to the official manual, the method is

1. particularly useful in combination with a retry mechanism.
2. helpful when used in conjunction with the connection timeout and connection harvesting features.

You of course can retry the method in the hope of the database issue resolves afterwards, but more generally you set a timeout and after that you may have to take appropriate action and close the connection.

```
try { conn = poolDataSouorce.getConnection ... } catch (SQLException sqlexc)
{
    if (conn == null || !((ValidConnection) conn).isValid())        
        // take the appropriate action   
    conn.close
}
```

For more information, please check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e10788/connect.htm#CHDIDEEB

Comment: How common is it for the driver to be invalid immediately after creation, e.g. here:  `jdbcDriver driver = new jdbcDriver(); boolean isValid = driver.isValid();`?

Comment: @VikR You tell us: it is your code, not a normal JDBC driver. I'd suggest you throw your code away, and start using plain JDBC connections from a data source, instead of introducing - what seems to be - unnecessary complications.